# How to confirm memcache memory increase?

Tags: redhat, memcached, memcache

Alright, I have downloaded /etc/sysconfig/memcache

And edited the file that contained `"PORT="11211"
USER="memcached"
MAXCONN="1024"
CACHESIZE="64"
OPTIONS=""` to 1000 cachesize. I uploaded the file back to the server. Now I know there is a way to check if the changes took effect, but I cant remember how. I tried "memcached-tool 127.0.0.1:11211 stats" but it didnt show me the RAM size.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean *downloaded* `/etc/sysconfig/memcache`? Do you mean to say that you created this file?

Answer (score 1):

The "stats" command should display the cache size as "limit_maxbytes".  For example, the following command:

```
[user@server ~]$ printf 'stats\n' | nc 127.0.0.1 11211 | grep limit_maxbytes
STAT limit_maxbytes 67108864
[user@server ~]$
```

In my case, I'm using the default of 64MB, but if I up it to 128 and restart, the value goes up accordingly.  Are you *SURE* that your "memcached-tool" output isn't showing the limit_maxbytes value?

Answer (score 0):

You could check using ps.

```
ps -eo cmd,size | grep -i memcached
```

from man ps.

> size =  memory size in kilobytes

Make sure that memcached has been loaded with data, I don't think it will request more memory then it is using so you may not hit your cachesize until it is full.

Answer (score 0):

You can `telnet` to the memcached server and get commands that way.  I.e.,

```
$ telnet localhost 11211
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
get cachesize
```

([source](http://memcached.org/))